# unable to install mediaelch on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package-management, dependencies, 14.04, media-manager

I am trying to install MediaElch after the upgrade from 13.XX removed it. 
I followed the instructions from the MediaElch website 
(http://www.kvibes.de/en/mediaelch/download/)

sudo add-apt-repository \ppa:kvibes/mediaelch

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mediaelch

The first two steps worked fine however the third one failed as below.

---

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

mediaelch : Depends: libqt5core5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable

### E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Can anyone help me out please ? I am very very new to Linux and just converted to Linux from Windows 8 out of frustration so please bear with me. My upgrade from 13 to 14 was a resonable success with no issues that I could tell.

I have even tried a suggestion on a website to download the package and edit something called the Package CONTROL File however I have had no success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest match to the missing libqt5core5 package in Ubuntu 14.04 is libqt5core5a (Qt 5 core module). The libqt5core5 package in Ubuntu 13.10 has the identical package description: Qt 5 core module. libqt5core5 and libqt5core5a are approximately the same size and they also have the same dependencies. The names of the installed files for libqt5core5 are the same (except for version numbers) as their counterpart matching installed files in libqt5core5a. So open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a  
sudo apt-get install mediaelch
```